# I am trying to centre a banner

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML and CSS.

I am trying to centre a banner at the top of the screen.

I have tried setting the margin left and right to auto, however when I try that, or text-align: center, nothing happens and I'm not sure why...

I placed the banner within a div.

```
<div class="bruceBanner">
 <a href="http://www.example.com">
    <img border="0" alt="XYZ Banner" src="http://www.fablevision.com/northstar/make/objects/banner3.gif" width="553" height="172">
</a>
</div>
```

And referenced its class like so.

```
.bruceBanner {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

The full html is below, in case of any mistakes I am unaware of.

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<title>XYZ Products</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="bruceBanner">
<a href="http://www.example.com">
    <img border="0" alt="XYZ Banner" src="http://bit.ly/1QSpdbq" width="553"    height="172">
</a>
 </div>



 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You have to set a width (for .bruceBanner).

Comment: @KirkBeard, excuse me. I didn't know that was american english, I thought it was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bruceBanner` is a `div` element.

`div` elements by default are block-level elements, meaning they take up 100% width.

You need to set a width smaller than 100% or change it's `display` to an `inline-block`.

```
.bruceBanner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `.`:

```
.bruceBanner {
^---
```

`.`  in CSS is for a class. without the dot, you're trying to style an unknown/illegal html tag `<bruceBanner>`

Comment: Worth mentioning for total new learners, don't add the period in `class="bruceBanner"`

Comment: I am afraid that this was just a mistake in copying over the content. Even with the .bruceBanner, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

```
.bruceBanner {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: From the site you just referenced: "Tip: Center aligning has no effect if the width property is not set (or set to 100%)."